# Uploading Multiple Files to Location and Updated Database

Tags: php, mysql

I have been working on a multi-image upload function that I can't seem to make work. It currently will only work if I have a single image uploaded. I can't figure out what is going wrong with this script.

This is the function to upload images:

```
    if(isset($_POST["btnSubmit"])){     
        $errors = array();

        $extension = array("jpeg","jpg","png","gif");

        $bytes = 1000000;
        $allowedKB = 10485760000;
        $totalBytes = $allowedKB * $bytes;

        $imgDir = "assets/users/".$userLoggedIn."/images/";

        if(isset($_FILES["files"])==false)
        {
            echo "<b>Please, Select the files to upload!!!</b>";
            return;
        }

        foreach($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"] as $key=>$tmp_name)
        {
            $uploadThisFile = true;

            $file_name=$_FILES["files"]["name"][$key];
            $file_tmp=$_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$key];

            $ext=pathinfo($file_name,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

            if(!in_array(strtolower($ext),$extension))
            {
                array_push($errors, "File type is invalid. Name:- ".$file_name);
                $uploadThisFile = false;
            }               

            if($_FILES["files"]["size"][$key] > $totalBytes){
                array_push($errors, "File size is too big. Name:- ".$file_name);
                $uploadThisFile = false;
            }

            if($uploadThisFile){
                $filename = basename($file_name,$ext);
                $newFileName = uniqid().$filename.$ext;

                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$key],$imgDir.$newFileName);

                // current date and time
                $date_added = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

                $imagePath = $imgDir.$newFileName;

                $query = "INSERT INTO images(date_added, added_by, image, deleted) VALUES('$date_added', '$userLoggedIn','$imagePath', 'no')";

                mysqli_query($con, $query);     
            }
        }

        header("Location: edit-images.php");

        $count = count($errors);

        if($count != 0){
            foreach($errors as $error){
                echo $error."<br/>";
            }
        }       
    }
?>
```

I thought the issue might be with size but I cut the condition to prevent it from uploading with no luck. I feel like I might be missing something in the foreach but I am completely stuck. I appreciate your help!

Here is the form I am using to upload:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="formUploadFile" id="uploadForm" action="edit-images.php">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputFile">Select file to upload:</label>
                <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile" name="files[]" multiple="multiple">
                <p class="help-block"><span class="label label-info">Note:</span> Please, Select the only images (.jpg, .jpeg, .png, .gif)</p>
            </div>          
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="btnSubmit" >Start Upload</button>
        </form>
```

Comment: Can you please share your html code. I think you are missing something in your html code. here is an html example of multiple file uploading -                                     
         <input type="file" name="files[]"  multiple>

Comment: I just edited my question to include the form. I appreciate you taking a look.

Comment: I executed your code in my local server. It's working fine. I think you should enable the debuging mode by setting error_reporting(1) in top of page. Hope this will show the exact error.

Comment: You were able to upload multiple images no problem? I appreciate you taking the time to do that. I will update you with what I find in my error reporting.